# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134mb exhausted

Tags: entries, php

I have a template in my control panel (technically a plugin, but it's just one template) which is running out of memory:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 78 bytes) in
>   /var/sites/t/thames-arbitrators.org.uk/craft/app/helpers/ModelHelper.php
>   on line 101

In my local dev site, the profiler is giving me the following info:

- Time 10.66053s
- Memory: 127,544Kb
- Total Queries: 381

Is there anything I can do to alleviate this? I've seen the answer to '[PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)' but there are only two conditionals in this template, it's almost certainly down to the fact that I need to return several hundred entries.

I don't mind posting my template here but there's a big table in it so it's going to make the page super long - let me know which bits you need.

Comment: Hi, we have the same issue on a entries template in the admin. Looks like the UserSessionService::getAuthTimeout() is using an abnormal amount of requests. Need a patch ASAP!

Comment: @DanG Your issue is most likely different and should be addressed in the next release.

Comment: @BradBell Thanks, and thanks for the update!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your plugin is pulling in a lot of data, then most likely you're just bumping into your php.ini file's [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting.  Try bumping that up to 256M and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll have to talk to the host and see if I can increase it. 134mb is already a hell of a lot though and the site's only been live for a month. It's going to increase by another hundred entries every month. Would pagination stop the overhead?

Comment: Maybe? Caching would likely be the first place to look, but it's hard to tell without seeing how your data is organized and your plugin code and what it's doing.

Comment: I tried caching the data to reduce the overhead but it was causing issues - you advised me that caching was never designed to be used inside the control panel :)

Comment: The {% cache %} tag wasn't,  but there are other ways of caching